# Jenkinsfile use array in environment

Tags: jenkins, groovy, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline

My code is using VALUES.each() method, it works fine when I have

```
environment{

    VALUES = "val1, val2"
}
```

But, I need to have a list from each line so that it can be read easily:

Something like:

```
environment {
VALUES =
 "val1",
 "val2"
}
```

I tried using [] and {} - didn't work, tried adding "\n" - no luck.

Tried using method def and then call it from environment:

```
def getArray(){
  return [
  'val1', 
  'val2'
  ]
}
```

but then it gives me "[val1" and "val2]"

Comment: Your question is not clear. Maybe you can provide more context and share the full pipeline with us.

Comment: in environment you could store only string values. you could use coma-separated value and then use `VALUES.split(',')` or you could use json-formatted value and each time when you need it as array - parse it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this one. I used this def method

```
    def values = """
        val1
        val2
                 """
```

My environment:

```
    environment {
     MY_VALUES = values.stripMargin()
}
```